# ZipArchive::setPassword doesn't set a password to my newly created file

Tags: php, passwords, zip, php-ziparchive

The new "setPassword" method doesn't take effect (unless I've misunderstood it).

This is my example code:

```
<?php
$zipFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'filename.zip';
$password = 'P455W0RD';

if (file_exists($zipFilePath)) {
    unlink($zipFilePath);
}

$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
$zipArchive->open($zipFilePath, ZipArchive::CREATE);

if ($zipArchive->setPassword($password)) {
    echo 'OK' . PHP_EOL;
}

foreach (range(1, 10) as $fileNumber) {
    $zipArchive->addFromString('file' . $fileNumber . '.txt', rand());
}

$zipArchive->close();
```

It does print "OK" in PHP 5.6.0beta3 (Debian Testing), but there is no password
in the zip file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you fed this back to the PHP core devs? They've been asking for test feedback of the new PHP56 features for quite some weeks now

Comment: Actually no. I've been thinking about it. I'm not sure if my code is silly or if it's a real bug ...

Comment: Perhaps it's worth modifying your code to test if setPassword() works _after_ adding the files... but it's certainly possible that it's a bug: this is a new feature after all, and I don't see any phpt files for testing setPassword

Comment: No, it doesn't work after adding the files. I'll report it them. Thanks!

Comment: Even if it's simply something silly that you're doing, logging a problem should alert the team to explaining how to use it properly in the php docs

Comment: I'm on 5.5.14 and it just crashes saying there isn't such function ZipArchive::setPassword().
in the documentation, http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php, it says (PHP 5 >= 5.6.0, PECL zip >= 1.12.4)
don't know what that means

Comment: same problem here. just installed php 5.6 for this feature on ZipArchive and it doesn't work. how do they add the function setPassword to the public api and official stable docs and don't even test the basic functionality of it > setting a password to a zip...?! does anyone know where to report this?

Comment: found it. also it seems the setPassword method is only for extracting purposes and not for encrypting the zip file. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67590

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to bypass the ZipArchive::setPassword() method. I simply wrote a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
command -v zipcloak && echo "exist" || exit -1;
command -v expect && echo "exist" || exit -1;
MYPWD="[password]"
expect -c ' 
spawn zipcloak [filename]
expect "*Enter password*" 
sleep 0.1
send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
sleep 0.1
expect "*Verify password*" 
sleep 0.1
send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
sleep 0.1
'
```

I can simply use exec from my php code:

```
public function encryptZip($filename, $password, $bashdir){
    $bash = str_replace('[filename]', $filename, (str_replace('[password]', $password, file_get_contents($bashdir))));
    exec($bash);
}
```

It works only on linux servers, where expect and zipcloak are installed.